# import the X-display of one local ubuntu user onto another user's desktop

Tags: unity, display, ubuntu-mate, xserver

Inspired from [this topic](https://superuser.com/questions/325630/how-can-i-export-display-from-a-linux-terminal-to-a-windows-pc) I dare ask this probably impossible question:

I have 4 different users on my Ubuntu-MATE 21.04 machine.
Sometimes it would be nice to see user2 on the display of user1, either in a Window (some sort of exported X-Window, rlogin,...) or even better, one of those 4 Workspace Panels:

[image]

So like Panel 1-3 for user 1, Panel 4 for user 2.
(I am aware that I can do `sudo - …`, `rlogin`, `ssh` on the command line to run certain commands as another user, but now+then I would truly need that other use with the actual GUI...)

*If there is a solution, perhaps it is in the world of `export DISPLAY=:0.0 NO_AT_BRIDGE=1` or in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654966/enable-x-display-access-for-local-user). Perhaps exporting is easy and I just need a rather dumb X-Display client? As you can tell, I have very little clue around Displays, XServer and Exports.*